# LaTeXの数式モードでマイナスが表示されない

Tags: eclipse, latex

LaTeXの数式モードでマイナスを使いたいのですが、表示されず困っております。
環境: Texlipse, Windows 10
エンジン: pLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx} %load extra symbols and environments
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %set margins
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{autobreak}

\begin{document}

\title{Mat}

\maketitle
$$S(\alpha , \beta , \gamma)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{y_{i}-(\alpha x_{i}^{2}+\beta x_{i}+\gamma)\}^2$$

\end{document}
```

たとえばこのコードを実行すると`y_{i}`と`(\alpha`の間にあるマイナスがうまく表示されません。これを表示させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
この[サイト](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/%7Eokumura/texonweb/)でコンパイルするとうまくいくんですが

log fileの中身も見ましたが、多分エラーなどはないと思います(見落としているだけかもしれませんので長くなってしまいますが、貼らせていただきます。)

```
This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.8.3-191112-2.6 (sjis) (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=platex 2020.12.8)  12 DEC 2020 16:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 Source specials enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**ni.tex
(./ni.tex
pLaTeX2e <2020-10-01>+1 (based on LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2)
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count176
\c@section=\count177
\c@subsection=\count178
\c@subsubsection=\count179
\c@paragraph=\count180
\c@subparagraph=\count181
\c@figure=\count182
\c@table=\count183
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen154
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvipdfmx.def on input line 105.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvipdfmx.def
File: dvipdfmx.def 2020/08/26 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for dvipdfmx
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen155
\Gin@req@width=\dimen156
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen157
\WF@size=\dimen158
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count184
\WF@box=\box64
\WF@everypar=\toks17
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen159
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen160
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count186
\leftroot@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count188
\DOTSCASE@=\count189
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box65
\strutbox@=\box66
\big@size=\dimen161
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count190
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count191
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count192
\dspbrk@lvl=\count193
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count194
\column@=\count195
\maxfields@=\count196
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen162
\alignsep@=\dimen163
\tagshift@=\dimen164
\tagwidth@=\dimen165
\totwidth@=\dimen166
\lineht@=\dimen167
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count197
\Gm@cntv=\count198
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count199
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen168
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen169
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen170
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen171
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen172
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen173
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen174
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen175
\Gm@dimlist=\toks23
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks24
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2020/03/24 v1.24 mathematical typesetting tools

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count266
\calc@Bcount=\count267
\calc@Adimen=\dimen176
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen177
\calc@Askip=\skip52
\calc@Bskip=\skip53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count268
\calc@Cskip=\skip54
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
)
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\('isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\)'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\['isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\]'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count269
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen178
\origjot=\skip55
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen179
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen180
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen181
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen182
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen183
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen184
\xmathstrut@box=\box67
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen185
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/autobreak/autobreak.sty
Package: autobreak 2017/02/23 v0.3 simple line breaking of long formulae
\everybeforeautobreak=\toks25
\everyafterautobreak=\toks26
\@autobreak@alltoks=\toks27
\@autobreak@linetoks=\toks28
\@autobreak@lhswidth=\dimen186
\@autobreak@rhswidth=\dimen187
\@autobreak@maxlhswidth=\dimen188
\@autobreak@realmaxlhswidth=\dimen189
\@autobreak@maxrhswidth=\dimen190
\c@@autobreak@eqnindex=\count270
\c@@autobreak@subeqnindex=\count271

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box68
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count272
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box69
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box70
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count273
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count274
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count275
) (./ni.aux)
\openout1 = `ni.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for JY1/mc/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for JT1/mc/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 15.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 15.


(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

[1

] (./ni.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3393 strings out of 479854
 49233 string characters out of 5884981
 340002 words of memory out of 5000000
 20681 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 414407 words of font info for 73 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 929 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 66i,6n,72p,244b,263s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on ni.dvi (1 page, 900 bytes).
```

もし何かわかりましたら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: コメント追加失礼します。

いろいろと試してみたところ、実際に生成されたpdfではマイナスがしっかりと表示されるのですが、ecipse内でのプレビューの時のみにマイナスが表示されないことがわかりました。

Comment: どうやらこれは LaTeX の問題ではなく Pdf4Eclipse のバグ (https://github.com/Borisvl/Pdf4Eclipse/issues/41) のようです．Zen さんが別に質問されていた find の件についても，原因は同根 (https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeXlipse#c876c383) と思われます．

Comment: バグなんですね。
教えてくださりありがとうございます